# cardinality of a semi-direct product

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Do the semi-direct product of two groups and their cartesian product have the same cardinality? I think they should be the same, because how multiplication is defined should not affect the size of the group. But I am not too sure about it.

Comment: They have the same underlying set, so their cardinality, which is the cardinality of the underlying set, is the same.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks

Comment: The more interesting question is, *why* you are unsure. Do you know the definition of an outer semidirect product, which starts with the Cartesian product? Or do you have another definition, where this is not so obvious?